# Parse several JSONOBject into an array in android

Tags: android, arrays, json

From the server I get a string with exactly the following format:

```
[{"valueOne", "341", "valueTwo": "1432"}, {"valueOne", "6483", "valueTwo": "3267"}]
```

I understand that it is two JSONObject into an array, but ..
Howparse this?

My intention is to have all the concatenated string values, like this:

```
Strings values = (341 + 1432 + 6483 + 3267);
```

I guess I must first convert the string that I have received from the server to JSONObject, but do not know how to continue.

In this example there are two JSONObjects, but sometimes may contain three or more.

Many times I get values from JSONObjects values, but I have never seen in this case. I searched for information but can not find a solution that is useful to me.

I appreciate the help

greetings!

Comment: which json package are you using?

Comment: The data you receive from the server is not a valid json.

Comment: The json is wrong formatted.

Comment: Oks, duplicated :( Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

```
JsonArray jArray= <your parsed array>;

for(int i=0;i<=jArray.lenght()-1;i++)
{
  String valueOne=jArray.getJsonObject(i).getString("ValueOne");
  String valueTwo=jArray.getJsonObject(i).getString("ValueTwo");
}
```

you can do whatever you want with the values.

Comment: you should also specify what packages you are using...